# Worldbuilding Moderator Status Update

Tags: discussion, moderators

Recently this question was asked:

[When do you fire a moderator?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6858/when-do-you-fire-a-moderator)

This specifically asked about the status of [JDługosz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jd%C5%82ugosz?tab=activity) who has been a Worldbuilding elected moderator since Feb 2017.

The simple answer is that we don't know where he is. He was an active and effective moderator for some time after he was elected and then activity dropped very low, and then eventually to nothing with no explanation and little communication. We hope he is well and thank him for his contribution during the time he was active, as it is important to remember that moderators are all unpaid positions with people giving up their time to help the community.

His absence and my own need to step back from spending a lot of time is why we held the election of July in this year. The election of two more moderators was to replace him and supplement me. In other words the moderator team is at full strength even with JDługosz absent and myself far less active than I used to be.

In the meantime we are in no rush to act as his presence as an elected moderator presents little to no risk. Even if his account were hacked (for example) all moderator actions are tracked, logged, and reversible. The Community Managers at Stack Exchange are aware of the situation and have made their own attempts to make contact and will take further steps as appropriate.

Comment: Indeed, thanks to JD for his contributions, especially as a tireless editor.

Comment: This is reasonable and sensible. Appropriate action had ready been taken. The good thing is moderation continues at full strength. JD had been very active, we can hope so he will be again. He contributed many good posts -- questions, answers & comments. An excellent editor too. I usually paid careful attention anything he posted, because quality was always there. WB was enriched by his presence. He deserves our thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds fair. If the Mod Squad is up to the task, and since this Summer's election, seems to be adequately staffed, then I'd see no reason to call for another election.

Also, if the election was planned & considered in light of JD's absence, then it seems rather pointless to even consider "firing" him. (Unless SE itself has reasons for doing so.)

As far as I'm concerned, just leave him on the payroll and try to contact him every now and then. If he wishes to relinquish his curious powers, then fine. If he expresses interest in returning, then fine too!

Comment: That's pretty much our view on it. There are a few minor concerns (for the sake of clarity if nothing else) so at some point if he doesn't return then the Community Managers will most likely take the decision to remove the diamond but beyond confirming that the CMs are aware of the situation the moderator team see no reason to take action at this time.

Comment: Great. And also, thanks for keeping us (the community) kind of in the loop. Not so much as to JD's whereabouts, but in general as to how things work behind the scenes and that there are actually people that look after this kind of thing!

Comment: Small nitpick... considering that elected moderators are just volunteering to give part of their time to keep the site clean and tidy, I would not use the word payroll. We get no monetary compensation for our service.

Comment: @L.Dutch -- that's my point exactly! You're nòt paid, therefore, there is no imperative for removing his diamond thingy as it doesn't cost us shareholders anything to keep him in his status. It's not worth the effort considering the "costs" of moderatorship for the community. While I understand your point, I consciously chose the word to indicate a particular perspective of irony.